# get files from folders in c#

Tags: file, c#-4.0, directory

im working on a website. there is a folder and .jpeg files inside , i need to get these files and but my code doesnt works here is my code:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/"));
List<FileInfo> fileList = ((FileInfo[])directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    .ToList<FileInfo>()
    .FindAll(imageName => imageName.Name == productDetail.ProductCode);
```

PS: folder path is correct(i dont know how many check.) but i cannot reach the files.... 
PS2: i tried directory and path class they doesnt work too.
where am i wrong.

Comment: Can you describe in what way it is not working? Exceptions? Excpected files in the result that do not appear there?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? If so, what?

Comment: fileinfolist count is always 0. i used directory and path classes before directoryinfo but result is the same, but there is  more than one image but i cannot reach them... and there is not any exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons:

- `Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/")` does not point to the directory you think it does
- `imageName.Name == productDetail.ProductCode` will perform a case sensitive comparison
- `image.Name` returns the filename *including extension*. I guess the ProductCode does not include this.

Suggested changed code:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/"));
var fileList = (directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    .ToList()
    .FindAll(imageName => string.Compare(imageName.Name, 
                              productDetail.ProductCode + imageName.Extension, 
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

This will add the file extension to the product code and then perform a case insensitive comparison to check if there is a match.

As a little tweak you can remove the `ToList` call in the middle and use the `Where` LINQ extension instead of `FindAll`:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/"));
var fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
    .Where(imageName => string.Compare(imageName.Name, 
                              productDetail.ProductCode + imageName.Extension, 
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Comment: thx fredrik. its imageName.name... i mean its me i should look at contains method not equal sorry i waste your time:)

Answer (score 0):

As a general suggestion, break down the extension methods into individual lines so you can debug through the problem. Once you find the line that blows up, you have a better chance of fixing the error than a chain of extension methods and lambdas.

NOTE: LINQ can be hard to debug, as it uses deferred execution, so you see it throwing context switches as you debug. But, if you separate out the bits, you can isolate the problem area.